# Not able to include 'sqlite3' in c program in ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, sqlite

I installed libsqlite3-dev from ubuntu software center and after the installation, i found the sqlite3.h file in usr/include folder. There was no error in including that header file, but i am not able to use the functions declared in it. It shows the error 'Undefined reference to sqlite_open' and same for all other functions declared in it. Is there a need for 'make' to build it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have to link with -lsqlite3 or such when you compile, that would add the sqlite functions to the compiled program

Comment: If i am using 'make', then do i need to have seperate folder for this library containing all the binaries and source code to be built and linked or could i somehow use the installed library(from ubuntu software center) with 'make' utility?

Comment: not for sqlite, that would have gotten installed into a system directory that is searched when you use -l.  You should add the link switch (-lsqlite3) to the makefile, though.  If you're asking if make in general needs a project directory, no it doesn't, but sometimes it's good to create one anyway, just to keep things organized.